# Removing a table from a google doc

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to GAS, and I'm trying to figure out how to list the elements in a DOC, in order to remove a table. I can't seem to find out reference for that, and the syntax of manipulating "children" is still beyond me.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Table Class .removeFromParent() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#removeFromParent()

```
function myFunction() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 var tables = body.getTables(); //THIS WILL GET ALL TABLES IN DOC
 tables[0].removeFromParent(); //THIS WILL REMOVE FIRST TABLE
}
```

Once you have the tables (var tables) you can loop through them as well if you want to remove multiple tables.